# Is there a way to print all memory addresses a variable is stored in?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-address

I want to know if there is a way to print all the memory locations that say an int variable is stored in.
Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        int x = 5;
        int *y = &x;
        printf("%p", (void*)y);
}
```

Example output: 0x100000000001

This will show the memory address that the first byte of x is stored in, but I want to see the memory address of each byte that it is stored in.
Is there any way to do this? Or do I just assume the following memory place values since they're consecutive?
i.e. the other memory locations of this int would be:

0x100000000002?

0x100000000003?

0x100000000004?

Comment: For a type that doesn't have any pointers the addresses will be consecutive.  But you would have to follow the pointers.  Think about `struct { int *p; } x;`  If you print the addresses there will be 8 for the pointer but the x.p might also point somewhere and it isn't consecutive - but if it did point somewhere there would be at least 4 more bytes that have addresses (and maybe more if p points to an array).

Comment: `for (char *p = (char *) &x; p < (char *) (&x+1); ++p) printf("%p\n", (void *) p);`.

Comment: Yes, they'll be consecutive. So it's all the addresses from `y` to `y + sizeof(x)-1`

Comment: The addresses will be consecutive in the sense that incrementing a byte pointer will step through them. The internal representation of the addresses will not necessarily consist of consecutive binary numbers, nor will the representation printed by `%p`.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil "The internal representation of the addresses will not necessarily consist of consecutive binary numbers, nor will the representation printed by %p" Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Tarik: Most modern systems use a “flat” address space where each byte of memory is numbered, and consecutive numbers are considered to be consecutive bytes of memory. But systems have used other methods of addressing, including segment and offset, base and offset, bank switching, hardware addressing of words with software supplements for bytes-within-words, and so on. Still, with any of these systems, the byte part tends to be last, so incrementing the whole representation by one increments the byte count by one. Except at transitions…

Comment: … For example, PDP-11s had a 16-bit base b and a 16-bit offset o with a six-bit shift (multiply by 64) between them, so a 32-bit pair (b, o) represented the address b•64+o. Then transitioning from base 123 offset 65535 (address 123•64+65535 = 73407) would not be offset 124 base 0 (124•64+0 = 7936) but rather base 1147 offset 0 (1147•64+0 = 73408) or base 124 offset 65472 (124•64+65472 = 73408) or some other combination to represent address 73408.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I understand that physically the bytes might end up anywhere in memory as per page mapping. However, from my understanding, the memory space from the point of view of the process is flat, starting at zero, ending I am not sure where. Accordingly, the bytes should always be consecutive, otherwise it would break applications relying on pointer arithmetics. I am not deep in OS internals and assembly, so bear with me.

Comment: @Tarik: Re “However, from my understanding, the memory space from the point of view of the process is flat”: This is not true in every computer, system, or C implementation.

Comment: @EricPostpischil That means that printing the pointers should consequently print consecutive addresses...or not?

Comment: @Tarik: The C standard does not require printing with `%p` to print an “address.” It says “The value of the pointer is converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an implementation-defined manner.” That just means the result of `%p` has to somehow represent the pointer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Mmmmh, ok! Thanks for your patience. It pays to read the standards :-) I have not used C much since the late 80's. It has been VB, FoxPro, VB.Net, C#, now Python. Not sure if I qualify as dinosaur  

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a way to print all the memory locations that say an int variable is stored in.

Sure.  Form a loop [0...sizeof(int)).

```
int main() {
  int x = 5;
  void *y = &x;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof x; i++) { 
    printf("%p\n", (void*)((char *)y + i));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the variable type in the compilation time, you can use `sizeof` to determinate the variable memory size (in bytes) and then assume that the addresses range is from `(char*)&var` to `(char*)&var + sizeof(var) - 1`.
If the variable is received as an allocated memory, you better use `malloc_usable_size` from `<malloc.h>` in order to get the variable size and then find the addresses range.
Note that usually operating-systems allocates virtual memory for processes.